# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when saving Image

Tags: c#, gdi, system.drawing.graphics

I read the answer for the same question and did whatever is asked to do. I also gave the write permission to the folder for current user as mentioned in one of the previous answer but still getting this error. So Please can anyone provide me the specific answer what is to be done?
This is my code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get all the files in a directory
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images");

    //combine them into one image
    System.Drawing.Bitmap stitchedImage = Combine(files);

    //save the new image
    stitchedImage.Save(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);//Error:-A generic error occurred in GDI+

}
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap Combine(string[] files)
{
    //read all images into memory
    List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> images = new List<System.Drawing.Bitmap>();
    System.Drawing.Bitmap finalImage = null;

    try
    {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        foreach (string image in files)
        {
            //create a Bitmap from the file and add it to the list
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image);

            //update the size of the final bitmap
            width += bitmap.Width;
            height = bitmap.Height > height ? bitmap.Height : height;

            images.Add(bitmap);
        }

        //create a bitmap to hold the combined image
        finalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);

        //get a graphics object from the image so we can draw on it
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))
        {
            //set background color
            g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

            //go through each image and draw it on the final image
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap image in images)
            {
                g.DrawImage(image,
                  new System.Drawing.Rectangle(offset, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
                offset += image.Width;
            }
        }

        return finalImage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (finalImage != null)
            finalImage.Dispose();

        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        //clean up memory
        foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap image in images)
        {
            image.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How large is the image?

Comment: You are loading images from `@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images"`, so that must be a directory -- but then you do [`stitchedImage.Save(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -- trying to overwrite the pre-existing directory with a *file* of the same name.  Try a different name.  The `string` argument to `Image.Save` is the file to which to save, not the directory to which to save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
stitchedImage.Save(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images\stitchedImage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

instead of

```
stitchedImage.Save(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The first argument to [`Image.Save (String, ImageFormat)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the file *name* to which to save, not the *directory* to which to save.  Previously you had done

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images");
```

So `@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images"` must be a directory, not a file.

(Incidentally, I suggest saving the stitched image to a different directory; otherwise, every time you run your code you'll stitch the previous stitch together with the previous contents.)

Answer (score 3):

```
stitchedImage.Save(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); - you need to specify the file name here. I.e edit it to something like this:     `stitchedImage.Save(@"D:\Naved\BasicDotNet\Images\myjpeg.Jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)`
```